# CommonsPoolTargetSource doesn't create objects

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am trying to implement the CommonsPoolTargetSource but I can't figure out what I need to do to get it to create my minimum objects at start? By reading the docs what I have in my app configuration should be the what I need to get started but tests show that the pool is at zero instead of the minimum I set which is 4.

Here is my App Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mf.bb"})
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public BBIDSApp bbIDSApp() {
        return new BBIDSApp();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsPoolTargetSource commonsPoolTargetSource() {      
        CommonsPoolTargetSource commonsPoolTargetSource = new CommonsPoolTargetSource();
        commonsPoolTargetSource.setMinIdle(4);
        commonsPoolTargetSource.setMaxSize(50);
        commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetBeanName("bbIDSApp");
        commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetClass(BBIDSApp.class);
        System.err.println("I'm alive!!!");
        return commonsPoolTargetSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean() {
        ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactoryBean.setTargetSource(commonsPoolTargetSource());
        return proxyFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean poolConfigAdvisor() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean poolConfigAdvisor = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        poolConfigAdvisor.setTargetObject(commonsPoolTargetSource());
        poolConfigAdvisor.setTargetMethod("getMaxIdle");
        return poolConfigAdvisor;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected, or better said it is working but not as you would expect it to. Not Spring's `CommonsPoolTargetSource` nor the normal Commons Pool's `GenericObjectPool` don't initialize the number of objects in pool by simply creating the pool object.

In Spring, `CommonsPoolTargetSource` creates the pool by calling `new GenericObjectPool(this)`. The same can be done with plain simple `GenericObjectPool`: `GenericObjectPool pool = new GenericObjectPool(new MyBeanFactory());` and in the constructor there is no initialization logic, so objects will not be created by default when the pool instance is created.

With plain old vanilla Commons Pool `GenericObjectPool` you can initialize the `minIdle` objects like this:

- manually:

  ```
  GenericObjectPool<MyBean> pool = new GenericObjectPool<MyBean>(new MyBeanFactory());
  pool.setMinIdle(4);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pool.addObject();
  }
  ```
- somewhat automatic, but ugly:

  ```
  GenericObjectPool<MyBean> pool = new GenericObjectPool<MyBean>(new MyBeanFactory());
  pool.setMinIdle(4);

  pool.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000);
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
  ```

With Spring's `CommonsPoolTargetSource` you don't have access to the pool instance or the `addObject()` method. So, you can either use the sleep() method (which is ugly) together with `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` or let the normal implementation to size the pool automatically when needed (objects are created when needed and added to the pool).

There would be another, third approach, of a custom CommonsPoolTargetSource that should include a init method:

```
public class CustomCommonsPoolTargetSource extends CommonsPoolTargetSource {
    public void initializeMinIdleObjects() throws Exception {
        List<BBIDSApp> apps = new ArrayList<BBIDSApp>();

        for(int i = 0; i < getMinIdle(); i++) {
            apps.add((BBIDSApp) this.getTarget());
        }

        for(BBIDSApp app : apps) {
            this.releaseTarget(app);
        }

        apps.clear();
    }
}
```

and then in your AppConfig:

```
@Bean(initMethod="initializeMinIdleObjects")
public CommonsPoolTargetSource commonsPoolTargetSource() {      
    CommonsPoolTargetSource commonsPoolTargetSource = new CustomCommonsPoolTargetSource();
    commonsPoolTargetSource.setMinIdle(4);
    commonsPoolTargetSource.setMaxSize(50);
    commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetBeanName("bbIDSApp");
    commonsPoolTargetSource.setTargetClass(BBIDSApp.class);
    System.err.println("I'm alive!!!");
    return commonsPoolTargetSource;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation ... any help with this plz.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881060/how-to-create-a-pool-of-bean-in-spring